# How does python "nonlocal" keyword implement? Can it save space?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I am thinking of writing a code to get maximum depth of a binarytree. Python can't pass *non-container* parameter by reference, so there are generally two choices, use `nonlocal` keyword or pass depth by copy.

The first one `get_max_depth1` need more traceback operation, I wonder whether it costs less space compare to `get_max_depth1`. If python implement `nonlocal` use parameter pass by reference, then every function also bring an integer pointer, in this case, it is inferior to `get_max_depth2`, because it's harder to write, slower to run, and save almost no space. If not, when the binary tree depth is 100000, `get_max_depth1` only need one variable, `get_max_depth2` need 100000 variable `d` saved in their function, I guess it's meaningful to write `d` outside.

```py
def main():
    root = BinaryTreeNode()
    d = 0
    maxd1 = 0
    def get_max_depth1(node):
        nonlocal d,maxd1
        maxd1 = max(maxd1, d)
        if node.left:
            d += 1
            get_max_depth1(node.left)
            d -= 1
        if node.right:
            d += 1
            get_max_depth1(node.right)
            d -= 1

    get_max_depth1(root)

    maxd2 = 0
    def get_max_depth2(node, d):
        nonlocal maxd2
        maxd2 = max(maxd2, d)

        if node.left:
            get_max_depth2(node.left, d+1)
        if node.right:
            get_max_depth2(node.right, d+1)

    get_max_depth2(root, 0)
```

Comment: i sugeest you to correct your code first, do right functional call with correct parameters

Comment: "Python can't pass non-container parameter by reference" *Python cannot pass anything be reference ever*. Python's evaluation strategy is the same for all types of objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Erm... isn't _everything_ in Python passed by reference, it's just that some objects are immutable and some aren't?

Comment: @AKX no. The problem is that the evaluation strategy called "pass by reference" originally meant something specific,  supported in languages like Fortran and C++, but it has warped into meaning "passing a reference". True call-by-reference semantics is when *assignment to the call-by-reference paramter is seen *by the caller**. The parameter acts as an alias to the variable in the caller's scope. E.g. something like (making up the `&` notation), `def foo(&x): x = 42`, then `y = 0; foo(y); print(y)` would print `42`. This is not supported in Python at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right you are, I didn't think about the other possible interpretation for the term. Like OP implies, you can emulate that sort of pass-by-reference by "boxing" your value in a list, though.

Comment: @AKX now, the name of Python's evaluation strategy is not consistent across the languages that use it. You can trace the origin back to the [CLU language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLU_(programming_language)) created by Barbara Liskov (of the Liskov Substitution Principle). There, it was referred to as "call by sharing". Java has the same evaluation strategy, but Java has two kinds of types, "reference types" and primitives. In that community, you hear "everything ic call by value but the value is an object reference".

Comment: Voyager - both your implementations take the same amount of space, modulo a few pointers maybe. It is really unclear what you hoped to accomplish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How do you know and why the implementations take the same amount of space? That is my question. I want to know the underlying mechansim in CPython

Comment: @Voyager again, the underlying mechanism of *what* exactly? In any case, you are using a closure in one instance, and a parameter in the other. The extra parameter basically requires an extra pointer, underneath the hood. The closure is not free, it amounts essentially to an extra pointer and a "cell", and actually a tuple to hold a cell for every free variable that is captured by the closure. The difference will be negligible, on the order of tens of bytes, but the important point is that *both* are constant space, so for practical purposes, *it doesn't matter*

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, you use a closure in `get_max_depth1`, and an extra paramter in `get_max_depth2`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What if the binary tree depth is 100000, then there are 100000 values of `d` instead of a nonlocal variable `d`.

Comment: @Voyager Ah, I think I see what you are getting at. But understand, it is not "100000 values of d". `d` is *just a reference to an object*. The object isn't copied  100000 times, but you might require that many extra auxiliary pointers..., but that is just a minor additional cost the the entire stack frame being used to perform the recursion in the first place (in both approaches), which dwarfs the memory required for the auxiliary pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) defines *User-defined functions* as having a `__closure__` attribute, which reify the [function closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)): the readable/writeable values of enclosing scopes. `__closure__` is `None` or a `tuple` of *cells*.
The standard currently (3.10) only defines that a cell has a `cell_contents` attribute to represent the value of the cell. [The `CellType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CellType) makes no guarantees what it provides.

Notably, whether a cell is writeable is *not* determined by whether a function captures the closure as readable (bare usage) or readable/writeable (`nonlocal` declaration). Both are the same kind of cell.

---

In practice, CPython¹ represents `__closure__` as a regular `tuple` and each cell as a 40 byte object that holds a pointer to its value.

```py
>>> def outer(a = 3):
...     def inner():
...         print(a)  # `a` is captured from outer scope
...     return inner
>>> outer()
<function __main__.outer.<locals>.inner()>
>>> outer().__closure__
(<cell at 0x10eac2ca0: int object at 0x109f26d30>,)
>>> outer().__closure__[0].cell_contents
3
>>> # size of the closure tuple and cell in bytes
>>> sys.getsizeof(outer().__closure__), sys.getsizeof(outer().__closure__[0])
(48, 40)
```

The `__closure__` itself belongs to the function object, whereas a `cell` is shared between all functions closing over the same variable.

In contrast, a local variable is stored as an array of pointers – each 8 byte. The local storage belongs to the function *call*, so calling a function multiple times also creates multiple such pointers.

For reference, just the shell of the above `inner` function object is 136 bytes. Its name and fully-qualified name are 54 and 69 bytes, respectively. Its bytecode is 45 bytes. There are many additional costs for things that you likely do not even know exist.
Keep that in mind when trying to safe individual chunks of 8 bytes.

---

¹CPython 3.8.12 [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)], 64 bit build.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find out exactly what the allocation difference is, then running the app with https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/ should give you the answers you're after. But that only applies to the very theoretical side and the result will be specific to one CPython version and may not hold overall.

In practice the answer is: they're about the same for a few reasons:

- Other code will dominate the performance (just creating new stack frames and would take more space)
- You can't go that deep anyway (default recursion limit is 1000 frames)
- Your data will not be that large (binary trees are usually kept balanced which at 100000 levels it would give you over `10^30102` elements)
- Once you start caring about single bytes and limits like that, CPython stops being the right answer. Cython may be the simplest next step and there you can check the exact heap/stack usage of the resulting C program.